# Assignment EOF of int to char behavior on ARM vs x86_64

Tags: casting, char, int, variable-assignment, eof

I am running this snippet of code both on ARM (iMX6) and intel 64 bits:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    int i = EOF;
    char d = i;

    printf("i = %d, d = %d\n", i, d);

    if (i == EOF)
        printf ("i is EOF\n");
    if (d == EOF)
        printf ("d is EOF\n");

    return 0;
}
```

In both cases, I compiled it with gcc 5.4:
ARM: gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609
x86_64: gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609

However, the results are very different:

ARM:

```
i = -1, d = 255
i is EOF
```

x86_64:

```
i = -1, d = -1
i is EOF
d is EOF
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is implementation-defined if `char` is signed (i.e. ranges from -128 to 127) or is unsigned (ranges from 0 to 255).

- In your combination of *ARM* and *gcc*, it's obviously unsigned.
  Therefore -1 is converted to 255.
- In your combination of *x86_64* and *gcc*, it's signed. Therefore, -1 is
  retained.

Comment: Yup, my bad. I somehow thought char was signed on every architecture...